# How to mix two functions for calculating the rate of change?

Tags: calculus

Imagine we have two functions for calculating the rate (say the internet for investment) as

$$y = 1 + \operatorname{erf}(x-2); 0 < x < 4\\
y = 1 + 1.5 + \operatorname{erf} (x-6); 4 < x < 8 $$

Is it possible to mix these two function into one to be valid for $0<x<8$?

Comment: Make it piecewise. Do you want it to have certain properties?

Comment: @saulspatz you're right, corrected.

Comment: @Kaynex I just prefer to have a single equation with a series of terms, which work only within their own domains. Something more universal than separated functions.

Comment: I mean, no matter what you do, it's going be an exact copy of the piecewise function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can write a piecewise function using a unit step function. The unit step function is itself a piecewise function but it allows one to write other piecewise functions as a single expression.

$$ U(x)=\begin{cases}0\text{ for }x<0\\1\text{ for }x\ge0\end{cases} $$

Then given

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
y_1\text{ for } x< x_1\\
y_2\text{ for }x_1\le x<x_2\\
y_3\text{ for }x_2\le x<x_3\\
\vdots\\
y_{n}\text{ for }x_{n-1}\le x<x_n\\
y_{n+1}\text{ for }x\ge x_n
\end{cases} $$

one may write

$$ f(x)=y_1+(y_2-y_1)U(x-x_1)+(y_3-y_2)U(x-x_2)+\cdots+(y_{n+1}-y_n)U(x-x_n) $$

In your example, define $y$ for $0<x<8$ as

$$ y=1+\operatorname{erf}(x-2)+\left[1.5+\operatorname{erf}(x-6)-\operatorname{erf}(x-2)\right]U(x-4) $$